# How to run a tcl script in NS2 when path in bash file is not found?

Tags: linux-mint, path, bashrc

i have added the path to where i have saved my tcl script (i.e. where ns2 is installed in home/me/ns-allinone-2.35). i have created a .bashrc and .bash_profile too, since they were not there.

In bashrc i have given the following path:

```
  $PATH=PATH:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35
```

in bash_profile the following:

```
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc fi
```

now when i type in my terminal:

```
  ns ns-simple-trace.tcl
```

i get the error:

```
  o: command not found
  bash:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35: No such file or directory
```

what should i do to get my 'ns-simple-trace' script running?

Comment: What do you get when you just type `ns` ?

Comment: i get a % sign.

Comment: copy a sample tcl file into `ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35` and try this: `./ns filename.tcl`. Does it work?

Comment: no it says: bash: ./ns: No such file or directory

Comment: i changed the path in .bashrc for this too to home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35

Comment: with or without changing the path the result is the same. it says no such file or directory.

Comment: do you have this directory at all? `ns-2.35`

Comment: yes it is there in ns-allinone-2.35

Comment: Ok, is there ns inside it?

Comment: no there is nothing named ns inside it but there is a document called ns.1, but it isnt a folder. its just a document.

Comment: So you should install it again.

Comment: please type this: `which ns` and report the result.

Comment: the whole thing? All of ns? i used the ns all at once installation as given here: http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-build.html#allinone. What am i supposed to have in the complete installation? cant i install just that instead of redoing the installation? i dont understand what the problem is..

Comment: after typing which ns i get: usr/bin/ns

Comment: ok, so go there (usr/bin/ns) and if ns is there try ./ns filename.tcl with an arbitrary tcl file.

Comment: i cant copy a file to usr/bin. you mean i should put the tcl script in bin?

Comment: No, I believe that you've installed ns2 incorrectly, but I said try that as a test, cause sometimes you can't run ns2 because wrong settings of bashrc not installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation of ns2 is a little tricky and I think you've not installed it correct.

Try this :

**1** :

Before install NS2, you have to install some essential softwares:

sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake 
sudo apt-get install perl xgraph libxt-dev libx11-dev libxmu-dev

**2** :

Download NS2 source file (“ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz“)

**3** :

Unpack ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz to your home directory. (/home/abc is my home directory, you SHOULD change it to your own!)

tar -zxvf ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz -C /home/abc

**4** :

Modify the makefile

gedit /home/abc/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14/Makefile.in

Change CC = @CC@ to CC = @CC@ -V 4.5

(NOTICE the V is capital.)

**5** :

Install NS2:

cd /home/abc/ns-allinone-2.35
sudo ./install

**6** :

Modify  .bahrc

gedit /home/abc/.bashrc

Go to the last line and add the scripts below:

export PATH=$PATH:/home/abc/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/abc/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/abc/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/abc/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/abc/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
export TCL_LIBRARY=$TCL_LIBRARY:/home/abc/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library

Enable the path setting:

cd /home/abc
source .bashrc

Comment: i have reinstalled it, but u have a slight problem, how should i remove the previous ns from usr/bin? i cant delete it from that place directly. How can i use the terminal to do it?

Comment: this 'ns' is in the filesystem and not in my home directory. but when i type which ns it gives usr/bin/ns instead of: /home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/bin/ns

Comment: I cannot test to see if after installation his way my tcl script is running because of the duplicate ns in my filesystem. But this installation procedure is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @pythonspark- You're welcome, sorry it was late in my country. I'm a little confused about the other ns installation that you say, cause indeed another installation shouldn't interfere.

Comment: can u please help with two errors that i am getting                        gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-V’
gcc: error: 4.5: No such file or directory. this happens at step 5 when i ./install. it says:  make: *** [libotcl.a] Error 1
otcl-1.14 make failed! Exiting ...

Comment: after removing the previous problem i reinstalled ns and i got the above errors. i think its due to the make file: v 4.5 isnt supported here may be. I am using linux mint.

Comment: @pythonspark- find the proper gcc version that is installed on your linux and change it in the make file.